# Go to next page without passing start,limit

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to go to next page in extjs dashboard without passing start and limit values...?I have some problem with the existing functionality.Plz suggest me any solution.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You check how much records you have and if pagenumber x items per page is higher than the result you don't show the button "next".

Comment: You mean to say I have to pass start and limit ahh???Let`s take i have to display 40 items/perpage,and i have 170 total records..